# iOS: Facebook SDK AppInvite error 9

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

For some reason I keep getting an error for the AppInvite Dialog...

After setting up the info.plist for iOS9 by the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9), setting all Facebook's parameters on the project, I get the error method being called with: `Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)"`.
App link was made on [Facebook's Hosting API](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host).

```
- (void) appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
}
```

the method I use to invoke the dialog:

```
-(void)inviteFriends{
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog* dia= [[FBSDKAppInviteDialog alloc] init];
    if ([dia canShow])
    {
        FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
        content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.applink];
        content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.preview_image];
        [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self.rootViewController.mainViewController withContent:content delegate:self];
    }
    [dia release];
    return;
}
```

I tried calling `inviteFriends` in different places, but it won't start and would get to the `didFailWithError` method.
However, for some reason it may start working all of a sudden, and would work all the time ever since, unless the app is deleted from the device and reinstalled. In this case, it won't open again...

Comment: If your app in dev mode, make sure both users are added to the FB app dashboard. Also, double-check you app link. Does the dialog appears at all, or you get an error even before the presentation? The implementation, you've posted looks the same as mine, so, there should not be a key factor.

Comment: The dialog does not show up at all

Comment: The user that is testing, is defined as a tester, I can see friends when the dialog shows up

Comment: What dialog you refers to when you are talking about the user's friends? Also, just in case, try to test it **without** the debugger attached to the process (FB has some nasty behaviour in some cases).

Comment: Hi Any Luck with that ? I am getting same error all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` in your AppDelegate. I've spend two days while trying to fix that.

Also make sure you have `[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];`
in `applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`